# Overcoming Java inheritance limitations (Opinions / Suggestions)

Tags: java, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

So I'm working on designing a framework for OpenGL/GLEs.

I have created a "Texture" abstract class. I have Texture2D and TextureCubemap inheriting from Texture. From Texture2D I have RenderTexture, and from TextureCubemap I have RenderTextureCubemap. Now this all works fine however both RenderTexture and RenderTextureCubemap share a good number of similarities. I would like to remove the redundancy currently between them. In other languages this would be the perfect spot for multiple inheritance however Java doesn't support this. My second idea was interfaces. The issue here is I cannot define bodies for interface methods so it doesn't really benefit me. Another option would be to create a "RenderTarget" class and add it as a member variable, while this would work, I'm not a fan of having to jump through a member variable each time I want to access the stuff held in "RenderTarget", it seems kind of clunky.

I'm wondering if anyone has any more elegant solutions they can suggest.

Edit: Here is a diagram as per request.
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of some form of class diagram? The description is fine, but a picture would be better.

Comment: Since Java 8, interfaces can have `default` methods, which _can_ have bodies.

Comment: @JornVernee I suspect this isn't the right use case for `default`.

Comment: Default methods still have an abstract heart, and are a part of a solution for the OP but not all of it. First, consider composition over inheritance. Chances are that'll cure most of the woes. Second, Java does support multiple inheritance of type. That's actually enough. Third, mixing in components instead of inheriting them leads naturally to use of dependency injection (DI) and all the beautiful magic that leads to.

Comment: @LewBloch By compositions are you referring to what I said at the end of the question "Another option would be to create a "RenderTarget" class and add it as a member variable..."? or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: If there are a lot of redundancy, given your inheritance tree, you could factor all your redundant code into the Texture class couldn't you?

Comment: @Asettouf The redundancy is only between the RenderTexture and RenderTextureCubemap, Texture2D and TextureCubemap are different, different constructors, etc. So it would quickly get out of hand if I push everything into the base class. Edit: Also, methods and stuff multiple levels down the inheritance tree I feel are to far removed from the base to really have any place there.

Comment: `RenderTarget` might indeed be something to inject into a class rather than inherit. Ask yourself, "Which is it, a `Renderer` _is a_ `Texture`, or a `Texture` _has a_ `Renderer`?" If the first, inherit. If the second, compose (inject).

Comment: @LewBloch A RenderTexture I would consider one thing, It's a texture that you can render to, although you can say it has a "Renderer" it wouldn't be as accurate. At the moment I'm treating it as a component and just adding it as a member variable, but it feels awkward because now most methods need to do "tex.renderer.getsomething()" when logically it should just be "tex.getsomething()" as for default inheritance cant do that because of platform constraints (at least for backwards comparability).

Comment: I support the composition over inheritance. If not too late :-}. Generics could also help you in this case

Answer (score 0):

Actually since Java 8 you can define a method body in interfaces, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html, so this could be a solution.

As suggested in the comments, a good solution is to put the redundant code in a different class and to compose it into both your renderer (i.e., create a member variable possessing this code).

Another possibility, if that applies here, would be to factor the redundancy into a helper class (noninstantiable and with only static methods) and poll its static methods from your 2 renderers.

Comment: this is true and would work well however I'm building for Android and sadly default methods in interfaces are only supported by API 24, I'm aiming to make this code backwards compatible so it rules this option out. But I agree, anyone looking for the generic Java answer should go this rout.

Comment: Not knowing what your code looks like does not help for sure, but if you absolutely want to avoid adding a "RendererTarget" variable, I would try to factor the redundancy inside a helper class (with static methods, you don't have to carry a full object). Now it has always been favored in Java to avoid multiple inheritance, for example this absence ensures you you don't have to bother with the diamond problem.

Comment: Be careful. Default methods are meant to express orchestration, not implementation. Don't make the mistake of treating them the same as concrete methods in an abstract class.

Comment: @LewBloch Not sure I follow. Also Asettouf It would take quite long to cut all the code apart into something easily understandable that fits on one page. Otherwise I would have added it.

Comment: I mean that it's tempting to put specific implementation into an interface's default methods, but too much detail is detrimental to the purpose of an interface, to define type. It's one thing to orchestrate the other interface methods, which doesn't require inside knowledge of how implementing classes do their thing. That's a good use of default methods. It's another to pull in dependencies, count on specific internal structures, and other such details. Be judicious so that the interface still only sets a pattern for implementors to follow.